# Cast based on variable

Tags: powershell, casting

I am trying to cast based on the value of a variable, ultimately to be able to actually test to see if $castFrom is of the $castTo type. I can of course do it with a switch like this

```
$castTo = '[xml]'
$castFrom = @"
<Settings>
    <MachineLogFileArchiveFolder></MachineLogFileArchiveFolder>
</Settings>
"@

switch ($castTo) {
    '[int]' {
        $castResult = [int]$castFrom
    }
    '[xml]' {
        $castResult = [xml]$castFrom
    }
}
```

But that's a little ugly. What I really want too do is something more like this

```
$castResult = [($castTo)]$castFrom
```

or this
    $castResult = [$($castTo)]$castFrom

but I am getting the impression the switch really is my only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use the `ToType` method:

```
$castResult =  $castFrom.ToType($castTo, [System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::CurrentInfo)
```

Somehow this doesn't work for your example but could be a starting point.

---

However, you can do this using the [**Invoke-Expression**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6) cmdlet:

```
$castResult = Invoke-Expression -Command ('[{0}]$castFrom' -f $castTo)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-as` and `-is` operators just seem simpler for this situation.

```
$castto = 'string'
$castfrom = 234
$castfrom.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType

$castresult = $castfrom -as $castto
$castresult.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

$castfrom -is $castto
False
$castresult -is $castto
True
```